# Create a rounded shape css for wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation, wordpress-theming

How I can make the rounded shape css in top bar navigation (especially for register menu, login menu, and cart icon) for my own custom wordpress theme like concept below:
[image: top bar]

Its style.css just for top bar navigation:

```
    .main-navigation2 {
    float: none;
    height: 50px;
    background: #fff;

}

.main-navigation2 ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.main-navigation2 li {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

.main-navigation2 a {
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #ff3400 url(img/arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right / 20% 20%;
}

.main-navigation2 ul ul {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5em;
    left: -999em;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.main-navigation2 ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
    top: 0;
}

.main-navigation2 ul ul a {
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: block;

}

.main-navigation2 ul ul li {

}

.main-navigation2 li:hover > a,
.main-navigation2 li.focus > a {
background: #e6370a;

}

.main-navigation2 ul ul :hover > a,
.main-navigation2 ul ul .focus > a {
}

.main-navigation2 ul ul a:hover,
.main-navigation2 ul ul a.focus {
}

.main-navigation2 ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation2 ul li.focus > ul {
    left: auto;
}

.main-navigation2 ul ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation2 ul ul li.focus > ul {
    left: 100%;
}

.main-navigation2 .current_page_item > a,
.main-navigation2 .current-menu-item > a,
.main-navigation2 .current_page_ancestor > a {
}


/* Small menu. */
.menu-toggle,
.main-navigation2.toggled ul,
.main-navigation.toggled ul {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
    .menu-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    .main-navigation ul {
        display: block;
    }
    .main-navigation2 ul {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

I already tried everything but still not luck

Updated #1:
[image: error]

I already added "border-radius" code to style.css like below:

```
.main-navigation2 a {
padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 50px;
color: #000;
font-family: sans-serif;
background: #ff3400 url(img/arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right / 20% 20%;
border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 124px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 124px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 124px;
border: 6px solid #ffffff;
}
```

but still not luck

Comment: Have you tried using border-radius: 5px?

Comment: If you're talking about the red shape that curves downwards to the nav menu, I'm pretty sure that's an image resource and not css.

Comment: @frosty Please check updated #1 above

Comment: @David Li How I can add image res so can fit with navigation margin?

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-radius` to element that you wanna make that rounded shape

eg. for register menu:

`border-radius: 0 0 0 50em;` and last icon should be `border-radius: 0 0 8px 0;`

or you can use border radius generator tools like http://border-radius.com/, http://www.cssmatic.com/border-radius

Comment: use .main-navigation2 a:first-child {} and .main-navigation2 a:last-child {}

Comment: I already added based on your suggestion because it will override other main-navigation2 css style like my screenshot: http://imgur.com/p9Af1Nl